# Mixing scala and java in Play Framework

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I have a Java file that looks like this:

```
package AuthorizeNetFingerprint;


class Fingerprint {
    private static Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(Fingerprint.class);

    private long sequence;
    private long timeStamp;
    private String fingerprintHash;

    private Fingerprint() {
    }

    /**
     * Creates a fingerprint with raw data fields.
     * 
     * @param loginID
     * @param transactionKey
     * @param sequence : this number will be concatenated with a random value
     * @param amount
     * @return A Fingerprint object.
     */
    public static String createFingerprint(String loginID,
                    String transactionKey, long sequence, String amount) {
         return transactionKey;
    }
}
```

And I am trying to access it like this scala:

```
val fingerprint = new AuthorizeNetFingerprint.Fingerprint
val x_fp_hash = fingerprint.createFingerprint(x_api_login_id,
                  transaction_key, x_fp_sequence, x_amount)
```

And it gives me this error:

object Fingerprint in package AuthorizeNetFingerprint cannot be accessed in package AuthorizeNetFingerprint

Is it possible to mix scala and java in Play Framework?

What I am doing wrong?

*EDIT*

I needed:
    public class Fingerprint

instead of

```
class Fingerprint
```

Answer (score 3):

Three things:

1. As you've already figured out, your Fingerprint class needs to be public.
2. You've made Fingerprint's constructor private; you can't instantiate it.
3. Any static methods in a Java class should be accessed through the class' companion object in Scala.

All the Scala code in your example should be replaced by:

```
val x_fp_hash = AuthorizeNetFingerprint.Fingerprint.createFingerprint(…)
```

This works in the Scala (2.9.1) console, compiled with sbt (0.11.3).

Yes, you can mix Java and Scala in a Play2 application, just put the Java code in the app directory. Note that Java classes need to be in their corresponding package directories, which is not the case for Scala classes.

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with the Play framework, but the first line in your Scala sample code should instantiate the class `AuthorizeNetFingerprint.Fingerprint`, which only has a **private constructor** and is not a **public class** (i.e., it can only be accessed from the same package).

Maybe a call to `AuthorizeNetFingerprint.Fingerprint.createFingerprint(...)` works, after making the class `public`?

Comment: the call to:

    AuthorizeNetFingerprint.Fingerprint.createFingerprint(...)

throws the same error. I am importing the package at the top of the scala script.

Comment: You should also make the `Fingerprint` class public (unless you are accessing it from the same package) - does this help?

Answer (score 0):

In theory this should work just fine. Check out this blog Re Java and Scala interop. 
http://www.codecommit.com/blog/java/interop-between-java-and-scala

When creating the project did you specify Java, Scala or None (1,2 or 3)

Comment: Can I specify none after creating the play project? Where can I set it to none? Am I supposed to set it to none?

Comment: If you check the Build.scala file in the project directory of your project you will see that most likely the language is specified as JAva. Now I'm guessing here, but I'ma ssuming something in the compilation stage of your project will expect to see only Java in your application code.

Comment: There is no such *setting*. The question is asked when a project is created and is only used to decide which sample controller (Java or Scala) to put in your application. You can add Scala code to a "Java" Play2 application and Java code to a "Scala" application.

Answer (score 0):

It's conventional to name Java packages in all lower case.

It also appears that Scala gets confused if you try to use a Java package that starts with  upper case.  If you use `authorize` as the package name instead of `AuthorizeNetFingerprint`, it will compile.

Also, there's no need for this:

```
val fingerprint = new AuthorizeNetFingerprint.Fingerprint
```

`createFingerprint` is a static method, so just call

```
val x_fp_hash = Fingerprint.createFingerprint
```

(after importing `authorize.Fingerprint`).