# Scala Enumeration use in java

Tags: scala, playframework-2.2, scala-java-interop

I have a scala Enumeration like this.

```
object WeekDay extends Enumeration {
    type WeekDay = Value
    val Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun = Value
  }
```

How can I use the class in Java?

```
public WeekDay getWeekDay() {
  return WeekDay.withName(this.myWeekDay);
}
```

It throws an error:

```
[error]   required: WeekDay
[error]   found:    Enumeration.Value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error tells you, the type of a Scala's [`Enumeration`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/rc/index.html#scala.Enumeration) members' is actually `Value`. So:

```
import scala.Enumeration.Value;
//...
public Value getWeekDay() {
      return WeekDay.withName(this.myWeekDay);
}
```

Unfortunately, [Scala type aliases are not visible from Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13673839/using-scala-type-aliases-from-java-code), so you can't use your `WeekDay.WeekDay` here.

Comment: It doesn't work. I got this error in the import statement. class Enumeration exists, but it has no companion object.

Comment: @angelokh : works fine for me. The error you're getting is typical to Scala (Java has no notion of "companion objects") and indeed appears when you place the import in **Scala code**. You **only** need this import in your **Java** code (`Enumeration` is in Scala's standard library and hence is auto-imported).

Comment: Thank you! But I still get the error. MyInfo.java:15: object Enumeration is not a member of package scala Note: class Enumeration exists, but it has no companion object. This is in java code.

Comment: My play version is 2.2 so scala version is 2.10.2.

Comment: @angelokh : it may be Java code, but it's still **being treated as Scala** by the build system. Maybe you have some basic problem, like the Java source file [not being placed in the correct directory (according to package naming conventions)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11381585/724361)? It could also be (albeit unlikely) some sort of bug. Regardless, this is a problem with your project setup, **not with Scala-Java interop per se**.

Comment: @angelokh : one more thing - out of curiosity I've decided to try it myself and I got the same error. However, **if you put *both* Java and Scala files into a package (e.g. `blah`) *and* the appropriate package folder (e.g. `app/blah`), the compiler *works* as it should** - both in Scala and Java projects. I suggest you ask a new question about why this is the case, since there's obviously something missing in the Play docs.